# Express with gravatar

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gravatar

I make web site with express and  I need gravatar image, 
so 
https://npmjs.org/package/gravatar

`npm install gravatar`

and my app.js

in my `app.js`

```
var gravatar = require('gravatar');
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  var secureUrl = gravatar.url('example@gmail.com' ,  {s: '100', r: 'x', d: 'retro'}, true);
  console.log(secureUrl);
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

working very well, and Browser show me nice picture.

but I use express, and use post method like this,

```
app.post('/signup', routes.signupResult);
```

and full of my example source `index.js`

```
exports.signupResult = function(req, res){
  res.render('user/signup-result', {
  title: 'Node-Chat Sign up'
  , name: req.body.name
  , email: req.body.email
  , password: req.body.password
  , password: req.body.passwordConfirmation
});
```

};

I want my signup-result.jade will use gravatar profile image...
what can I do my `app.js` to `routes/index.js` edit for gravatar?

Comment: oh my ..   using var gravatar = require('gravatar'); inside index.js.
it's done

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot to `require` the `gravatar` lib in your index.js file.

Add this at the top :

`var gravatar = require('gravatar');`

And also, in your render call add this

`avatar: gravatar.url(req.body.email ,  {s: '100', r: 'x', d: 'retro'}, true)`.

Comment: You're welcome @ChangJuPark :-)

If it's okay with you, you can mark my answer as accepted, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

i always use this code for getting a gravatar:

```
  <?php
$userMail = "google@google.com";

$imageWidth = '150';

$imgUrl = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.md5($userMail).'fs='.$imageWidth;

echo "<img src=\"" . $imgUrl . "\">";
?>
```

by the way i don't know if that email really exists

Comment: i do my best Joe John